# Custom Subdomain for Google App Engine Service

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, dns, subdomain

I have a web application running in Google App Engine right now under the default service for the GCP project. Let's say I own a domain `domain.com` which is registered and currently serves up a website on a locally managed server separate from Google Cloud.

I want to add the subdomain `api.domain.com` to point to the App Engine service but the method of registering custom domains in GCP doesn't really seem too friendly to this scenario. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding their documentation.

Is there a way for me to add a custom *subdomain only* in my App Engine project (`api.domain.com`) that points to my service, while the root `domain.com` points to a non-Google Cloud service?

Comment: `api.domain.com` is subdomain of `domain.com`, `domain.com` is subdomain of `com`... there really shoulld be no difference, perhaps you should just try and do it :)

Comment: @DusanBajic I have tried it but even after following the instructions given by GCP for verifying the domain/subdomain, it never seems to propagate

Comment: That will be difficult to troubleshoot further unless you provide real domain name... but maybe we can try if you provide screenshots of your DNS console

Comment: i know it's been 4 years, but do you remember if you had to add the CNAME record AND the A record for the subdomain? it's not possible because it causes a conflict, they cannot both point to the same host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console is a little confusing in this respect, but it can be done. You start here:

```
Console -> App Engine -> Settings -> Custom Domains -> Add a Custom Domain
```

The first step is to pick your domain and here you use the naked domain.  You have to prove to Google that you own the domain, but you don't actually need to use the naked domain with Google.  Many people don't use the naked domain and instead use www.mydomain.com.

The second step is to pick the subdomain that you want to map to your GAE service and you simply type this in the box.

You'll then set DNS records for A and AAAA for the subdomain so the subdomain maps to GAE.

Comment: That's neat! Is it possible to map 2 services to different custom subdomains at the same time? Like dev and prod? Or even Container Registry images? And all this within one project?

Comment: thank you! when mapping the subdomain to App Engine it asks me to add A record, AAAA record AND a CNAME record, but I cannot add the CNAME record because it points to the same host. Is it okey to add the A and AAAA records only?

Comment: still struggling with this, very confusing process :-( So just the A and AAAA records are fine, you didn't need to add the CNAME also? I have a conflict when I try to do this because both CNAME and A point to the same host but that's not allowed. Even posted a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76276067/app-engine-subdomain-cname-record-and-cpanel-subdomains?noredirect=1#comment134509065_76276067